# Connect to host socket from within docker container

Tags: docker, unix-socket, socat

I want to connect to a unix domain socket on the host from within a docker container. Specifically, I run this on the host:

```
socat - ABSTRACT-LISTEN:/tmp/.X11-unix/X1
```

And run this in the container:

```
socat ABSTRACT-CONNECT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X1 -
```

The expected result is bidirectional communication. But this is met only when the container is run with `--net=host`:

```
docker run -it --net=host ubuntu bash
```

Omitting `--net=host` gives me `ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

Question: Why does `--net` matter for a unix domain socket connection?

Question: Is it best practice to use `--net=host` only for allowing unix domain socket connection?

Answer (score 1):

One of the key selling points of docker is isolation. Using `--net=host` loosens the network isolation, and while you can definitely use for some cases, I would usually consider it a "code smell", and try other ways first.

In your case, I believe you need to mount any socket you want available in the containers (untested).

```
$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/X1:/tmp/.X11-unix/X1 ...
```